# Windows store app deployment error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, deployment, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I just downloaded and installed Visual studio on my computer (windows 8.1) to start building windows 8 apps. The problem is when I try to run any application this error message shows up (the application from this error message is called Parcels.comStarter):

> Error 1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Deployment
>   Register operation on Package
>   a783768f-d79c-495b-bf64-e59e4297fb42_1.0.0.0_neutral__1mfyfctfxa0tr
>   from: 
>   (d:\Gebruikers\wardv_000\Downloads\Parcels.comStarter\Parcels.comStarter\Parcels.com\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml)
>   failed with error 0x8E5E0530. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>   deployment issues. (0x80073cf9)   Parcels.com

I searched the entire internet but I didn't found a solution. I also did reinstall visual studio and I still have the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the Services management console (services.msc) and stop the Windows Installer service.
2. In Windows Explorer, go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\ and rename    PackageRepository.edb to PackageRepository.edb.backup.
3. Back in the management console, restart the Windows Installer service.
4. Now run Visual Studio as an administrator and open your project.

Comment: I think on win81 one should for 1. stop the "AppX Deployment Service" at least in my case stopping this service did the job :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact same problem, and the solution for me was to unlink my Windows account from my Microsoft account.

Comment: Haha you are lucky you found that solution. The solution for me was to format my hdd and reinstall windows...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to try.

- Run WSReset (press [Win] then type wsreset)
- Delete the `metastore` and `remotemetastore` folder here: `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\SettingSync` where `%userprofile%` is your username. (I suggest just renaming them to `metastore.old` and `remotemetastore.old`)
- Make sure that there are no `staged packages` for the app in question.

Comment: This is worth trying before the bountied answer as it's quick to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-deployed an app that was already installed by some other user, then you would get a deployment error. This should wear off if you change the `identity` in your `package.appxmanifest` fie.

Answer (score 0):

You should try an OS refresh. You should not lose your apps and settings. 
After that re-link your windows account to microsoft account.

If that doesnt work...The problem may be that visual studio is not able to delete the application data in local folder. So when you go in the location `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages` you will find application data of app installed in your computer, now you need to find your app's application data and delete the folder. The folder name is the same as the package family name which you can see in your solution.
now again open the solution and rebuild and your app will run. (hopefully)

1. close visual studio and simulator before deleting the folder.
2. make sure that your account is set as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with visual studio running under Parallels VM. The solution was to copy the project from a cloud based directory to a local directory.